# How do I change state or counties label sizes in R with the function usmap?

Tags: r, usmap

I am trying to map New Mexico with each county labeled, but the label size is always much larger than desired. 
Here is the code I have used so far.

```
plot_usmap("counties", include=("NM"), labels=TRUE, label_color="red")
```

and my map ends up looking like this:

[image: map]

How do I change the size of the labels to make them not over lap?
I have tried size= but that only changed the size of the boarders.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the label font size using the following solution:

```
library(usmap)
p <- plot_usmap("counties", include=("NM"), labels=TRUE, label_color="red")

# Set label font size
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size <- 5
print(p)
```

[image]